# Рисование в WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, графика

В WinForms очень просто можно было рисовать через Graphics, только все это было очень медленно. В WPF, насколько я знаю, прорисовка идет через DirectX, что в разы быстрее, но если там возможность так же напрямую использовать графический контекст?

Comment: Напрямую нет, только с использованием специальных библиотек. Впрочем, вам никто не мешает продолжать рисовать на Bitmap с помощью того же Graphics. А так, есть контрол Canvas и если мышкой рисовать, то InkCanvas.

Comment: И этот Graphics уже будет ускорен видеокартой?

Comment: Точно так же как и в Winforms, разницы никакой, одна и та же библиотека. По поводу полноценности аппаратного ускорения GDI+ я не уверен, но работает он весьма быстро. Все зависит от ваших задач. Например попиксельная обработка FullHD изображения может занять 2 секунды, а если оптимизировать - 4 миллисекунды. Вывод на экран картинки тоже достаточно быстрый.